# Automating a php-info file creation and deletion process

Tags: apache-httpd, php

How can one automate the creation and deletion process of a php info file?

Automatic deletion is good in case one wants to be covered from cases it forgets to delete the file and then the file is available from browser in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use a `cat` herestring with `at`:

```
document_root=/var/www/html
cat > "$document_root"/info.php <<< "<?php phpinfo();"
echo "rm $document_root/info.php" | at now + 30 minutes
```

`cat` concatenates the `<?php phpinfo();` code into the `info.php` file and the file is deleted after 30 minutes which is usually enough to gather the data from it.